# Serilog serializing fields

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, seq, seq-logging

If I have the following class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name;
}
```

and then have the following log command in Serilog

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
    .CreateLogger();

var item = new Customer();
item.Name = "John";
Serilog.Log.Information("Customer {@item}", item);
```

The log just displays in Seq as

```
Customer {}
```

If I change the Name field to a property it works but I would prefer not to do that at this stage. Is there any way around it?

Comment: One option might be to use the ``Destructure`` configuration object on ``LoggerConfiguration``, as described here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#customizing-the-stored-data

Comment: Is it working when `Name` is property?

Comment: Yes, if I make Name a property it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this just for the one type (recommended), you can use:

```
.Destructure.ByTransforming<Customer>(c => new { c.Name })
```

If you want to include public fields for all types, or those matching some kind of condition, you can plug in a policy to do it:

```
class IncludePublicFieldsPolicy : IDestructuringPolicy
{
    public bool TryDestructure(
        object value,
        ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory,
        out LogEventPropertyValue result)
    {
        if (!(value is SomeBaseType))
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        var fieldsWithValues = value.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields
            .Where(f => f.IsPublic)
            .Select(f => new LogEventProperty(f.Name,
               propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(f.GetValue(value))));

        result = new StructureValue(fieldsWithValues);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The example scopes this down to look at objects derived from `SomeBaseType` only.

You can plug it in with:

```
.Destructure.With<IncludePublicFieldsPolicy>()
```

(I think it's likely to require some tweaking, but should be a good starting point.)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Nicholas Blumhardt for a good starting point. I just have a small tweak.

my class:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public string Field = "the field";
    public string Property { get; set; } = "the property";
}
```

log call:

```
Log.Information("Dummy = {@Dummy}", new Dummy());
```

IDestructuringPolicy implementation includes both fields and properties:

```
internal class IncludePublicFieldsPolicy : IDestructuringPolicy
{
    public bool TryDestructure(object value, ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory, out LogEventPropertyValue result)
    {
        var typeInfo = value.GetType().GetTypeInfo();

        var fieldsWithValues = typeInfo
            .DeclaredFields
            .Where(f => f.IsPublic)
            .Select(f =>
            {
                var val = f.GetValue(value);
                var propval = propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(val);
                var ret = new LogEventProperty(f.Name, propval);
                return ret;
            })
        ;

        var propertiesWithValues = typeInfo
            .DeclaredProperties
            .Where(f => f.CanRead)
            .Select(f =>
            {
                var val = f.GetValue(value);
                var propval = propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(val);
                var ret = new LogEventProperty(f.Name, propval);
                return ret;
            })
        ;

        result = new StructureValue(fieldsWithValues.Union(propertiesWithValues));
        return true;
    }
}
```